# Visible zoom level for GroundOverlay in KML?

Tags: kml, arcgis, google-earth

First off, I apologize if this is a novice question and/or if it has been asked already.  I'm new to KML and so far, searching for 'GroundOverlay' and 'zoom' hasn't helped me.

I have created a KMZ file from an ESRI ArcGIS Layer.  The KMZ includes a GroundOverlay (which is a PNG image).  The KMZ opens and works fine in Google Earth, but now I would like to limit its visibility.  My data is for the continental 48 US States and is meant to be viewed as such.  So, zooming in to a 500-mile eye alt in Google Earth doesn't do the user any good.  Is there a setting for GroundOverlay that turns its visibility off when the user is zoomed in to a specific level in Google Earth?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a Region element to your GroundOverlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making features visible in Google Earth when you're zoomed in/out can be controlled by adding a [Region](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#region) to your GroundOverlay. Same concept works for any KML Feature (i.e., Document, Folder, Placemark, GroundOverlay, NetworkLink, etc.)

You can simply add a Region to your GroundOverlay with *maxLodPixels* value to make it disappear when you're zoomed in. A more advanced setup could have smaller region-sized image overlays rather than a singe continent-sized overlay where each GroundOverlay has a Region for when when that overlay is visible. The visibility of the Region is defined when the bounds of the region (via [LatLonAltBox](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#latlonaltbox)) with respect to a minimum or maximum pixel size.

Note, however, that Google Earth won't let you create or edit a Region on a GroundOverlay directly so you'll need to add that to your KML outside of Google Earth. This and other limitations in Google Earth are listed [here](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#limits).

To get a feel for pixel sizes on the screen and create appropriate minimum pixel size (*minLodPixels*) and maximum size (*maxLodPixels*) you can measure the "screen" pixels dimensions with the [KML screen ruler](https://github.com/googlemaps/kml-samples/blob/gh-pages/kml/Region/screen-rulers.kml). Click "Raw" link to view raw KML then save locally and launch in Google Earth.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick! I added a Region element to my Ground Overlay.  A maxLodPixels value of 75000 seems to do it. Thank you!